# How to determine what causes redirecting a page?

Tags: redirection, hyperlink, links

I have a link that should get me to LinkedIn portal and automatically add a certificate. The link is created by an Organisation that issues this certificate and they can manage and share these links through their LinkedIn organisational account and give it to every participant who wants.

When I click this link instead of doing what it should do, it redirects me to the main page. I would like to know what causes that, eg. someone did a typo pasting a link to a hyperlink and it misses some `&` or `%` sign (or whatever), or I would like to get some kind of an error saying that this link references to eg. *Languages* and not *Certificates* and therefore data provided within the link are invalid (not applicable to *Languages*, since "Workshops on project management" is not a language). Is that possible?

Comment: Look at the developer tab in your browser of choice. It will show you the redirection together with it's reason.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy! I might have a question more - the results are warning: "'webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL' instead."
error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Can I troubleshoot it somehow?

Comment: [Chrome Javascript error "WebkitURL is deprecated"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31629940) suggests it won't affect what is going on but who knows for sure ...

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" report the error to the website and/or whoever supplied the link.

Comment: See my answer for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When I click this link instead of doing what it should do, it redirects me to the main page.

Look at the developer tab in your browser of choice. It will show you the redirection together with it's reason.

> warning: "'webkitURL' is deprecated.

This is just a warning and can be ignored.

> error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
>
> Can I troubleshoot it somehow?

No. Report the error to the website and/or whoever supplied the link.

Note that the troubleshooting steps below cannot be done by the end user.

---

#### Troubleshooting 404 Not Found?

> The 404 status code, or a Not Found error, means that the user is able
> to communicate with the server but it is unable to locate the
> requested file or resource.
>
> 404 errors can occur in a large variety of situations. If the user is
> unexpectedly receiving a 404 Not Found error, here are some questions
> to ask while troubleshooting:
>
> - Does the link that directed the user to your server resource have a typographical error in it?
> - Did the user type in the wrong URL?
> - Does the file exist in the correct location on the server? Was the resource was moved or deleted on the server?
> - Does the server configuration have the correct document root location?
> - Does the user that owns the web server worker process have privileges to traverse to the directory that the requested file is in?
>   (Hint: directories require read and execute permissions to be
>   accessed)
> - Is the resource being accessed a symbolic link? If so, ensure the web server is configured to follow symbolic links

Source [How To Troubleshoot Common HTTP Error Codes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-troubleshoot-common-http-error-codes)

Comment: that's what I needed to know. thank you for your help!